# IP Blacklisting in Istio

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, docker-for-mac, kube-proxy

The IP whitelisting/blacklisting example explained here https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/ uses source.ip attribute. However, in kubernetes (kubernetes cluster running on docker-for-desktop) source.ip returns the IP of kube-proxy. A suggested workaround is to use `request.headers["X-Real-IP"]`, however it doesn't seem to work and returns kube-proxy IP in docker-for-desktop in mac.

https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7328 mentions this issue and states:

> With a proxy that terminates the client connection and opens a new connection to your nodes/endpoints. In such cases the source IP will always be that of the cloud LB, not that of the client.
>
> With a packet forwarder, such that requests from the client sent to the loadbalancer VIP end up at the node with the source IP of the client, not an intermediate proxy.
>
> Loadbalancers in the first category must use an *agreed upon protocol* between the loadbalancer and backend to communicate the true client IP such as the HTTP X-FORWARDED-FOR header, or the proxy protocol.

Can someone please help how can we define a protocol to get the client IP from the loadbalancer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your are confusing with kube-proxy and istio, by default Kubernetes uses kube-proxy but you can install istio that injects a new proxy per pod to control the traffic in both directions to the services inside the pod.

With that said you can install istio on your cluster and enable it for only the services you need and apply a blacklisting using the istio mechanisms

https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/denial-and-list/

To make a blacklist using the source IP we have to leave istio manage how to fetch the source IP address and use som configuration like this taken from  the docs:

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: handler
metadata:
  name: whitelistip
spec:
  compiledAdapter: listchecker
  params:
    # providerUrl: ordinarily black and white lists are maintained
    # externally and fetched asynchronously using the providerUrl.
    overrides: ["10.57.0.0/16"]  # overrides provide a static list
    blacklist: false
    entryType: IP_ADDRESSES
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: instance
metadata:
  name: sourceip
spec:
  compiledTemplate: listentry
  params:
    value: source.ip | ip("0.0.0.0")
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: rule
metadata:
  name: checkip
spec:
  match: source.labels["istio"] == "ingressgateway"
  actions:
  - handler: whitelistip
    instances: [ sourceip ]
---
```

You can use the param `providerURL` to maintain an external list.

Also check to use `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` on the ingress-gateway servce of istio.

As per comments my last advice is to use a different ingress-controller to avoid the use of kube-proxy, my recomendation is to use the nginx-controller

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx

You can configure this ingress as a regular nginx acting as a proxy

Comment: Thanks @wolmi. But, if I have to blacklist a specific set of IPs from accessing my service, how can I do that? source.ip doesnot give the IP of the client, but that of the ingress gateway.

Comment: I tried this. However, source.ip is always the same and is the ingress-gateway's IP

Comment: Thanks! I tried, it doesn't seem to work on docker-for-mac. source.ip is now kube-proxy IP always. In the docs, I see that it's supported only on GKE and Azure. Does that mean there is no solution for it on other clusters?

Comment: You have an open issue https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/180 but I updated my answer with an extra option