# How do i blacklist a domain name from kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, firewall

I want to make sure my kubernetes cluster doesnt talk to a specific domain name (*.domain.tld).  How can I blacklist it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking into [Network Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) but I think only IP's can be blocked not domains.

I think this might be achievable with [istio](https://istio.io/) and policy enforcement, this is explained at [Denials and White/Black Listing](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/denial-and-list/).

You can also check out this Stack question [IP Blacklisting in Istio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57026337/ip-blacklisting-in-istio).